# What does this error mean? "C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc"

Tags: c++

When compiling my program below, I'm getting an error message which I don't really So far, all I'm wanting my code to do is read in a file specified from the command line, and then output a new file with the name changed to having an 'o' at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string output_file_name(string file_name)
{   
    string output_file_name;
    file_name.pop_back();
    string ch = "o";
    output_file_name=file_name + ch;

    return output_file_name;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string file_name;

    file_name = argv[1];

    ifstream input_file(file_name);
    ofstream output_file(output_file_name(file_name));

    if(input_file.is_open())
    {
        string line;

        while(getline(input_file, line))
        { 
            //will put code here in future
        }
    }

    input_file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
D:\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\string(36): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc 
    
D:\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\string(83): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::getline<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &&,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const _Elem)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Elem=char
        ]
preprocess.cpp(47): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::getline<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' being compiled
```

Comment: how do you compile? Can you show the command you use to invoke the compiler?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that function `output_file_name` is more complex than it needs to be. It can simply assign the character `'o'` to the last position in the input string: `file_name.back() = 'o'; return file_name;`

Comment: @dunkirk What you are encountering is documented in detail on MSDN: [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4530](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4530?view=msvc-170)

Comment: i used cl preprocess.cpp to compile, preprocess being the name of this file @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: using cl /EHsc preprocess.cpp worked and didn't give me this error thanks @RemyLebeau